# Strange performance difference

Tags: python, optimization, primes

For exercise, I wrote this code:

```
def BigPrime(numP, plist = [], x = 1, counter =0):
    while len(plist) <= numP:
        if x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 5:
                plist.append(x)
        elif x % 2 is not 0 and int(str(x)[-1]) is not 5:
                for div in plist[1:]:
                        if x % div == 0:
                                break
                else:
                        plist.append(x)
                counter += 1
        x += 1
    return plist, counter
```

It is a simple algorithm that should return a list of the first *n* primes.  When I tried to optimize it, I wanted to cut down all the possible already know not primes from the range.  That brought me to:

```
int(str(x)[-1]) is not 5
```

But then when I timed it, I saw that the code ran slower. Why?  It worked, and the `for` iterations were less indeed, but yet it was slower.

Also, when it comes to optimization, I'm a black hole of ignorance.  Any further way I could improve it?

Comment: 1 is not a prime.

Comment: Yeah you're right, the number 1 has been excluded from the prime numbers. We can say that the number 1 is kind of inconvenient for the mathematical pattern of prime numbers, we can say that you can factor any non prime number into a product of primes, like: 24 = 3 * 2^3. If we include the 1 we can write it like: 24 = 3 * 2^3 * 1^153 and nothing would change. But 1 still remains a prime afterall because he follow the general rules nPrime = 1 x nPrime ( 1 = 1 x 1 ).
I just don't care being this formal for this little algorithm :)

Comment: Putting 1 into `plist` forces you to write the loop as `for div in plist[1:]:` whereas if you left it out you could write `for div in plist:` and avoid the copy.

Comment: True that! Being lazy almost never pays back. Thank you!

Comment: Aside: don't use `is not 0`, use `!= 0`; `is` tests identity, and you want to test equality.  It's only an implementation detail that it works at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well for starters:

`int(str(x)[-1])` is a really expensive operation:

1. Go from integer (x) to a string that represents X
2. Get the last element as a char [-1]
3. Transform that char back to an integer

Given what you're trying to do (find if the last digit is a 5), the same operation can be achieved with `x%10==5` or `x%51=5` (all integer operations, way less expensive).  This could be damaging your performance a lot.

Doing a quick experiment:

```
$> def test1():
    k = time.clock()
    s = int(str(55)[-1]) is not 4
    t = time.clock()
    print(t-k)

$> def test2():
     k = time.clock()
     s = (55%10 != 4)
     t = time.clock()
     print(t-k)
```

---

```
$> test1()
1.682255089008322e-05
$> test2()
1.7107678900174506e-06
```

`test2()` takes one order of magnitude less than `test1()` just because of the type of operations.

For your problem space, I think trying to find useful properties of prime numbers that you can exploit is the best way to optimize.  For example, a number `N` doesn't have a prime divisor greater than `Sqrt(N)`.

Comment: Well, that's what i feared. I tried that way because i thought that as it went further and further with the numbers it would become harder simply dividing by 5 than just looking at the last digit. Is that option always faster than the other? At what order of magnitude could change?

Comment: I can't answer all of the details as it would depend a lot on how Python implements some operations internally, but I think I can guarantee you that dividing by 5 will always be cheaper, because going from an integer to a string always requires at least 1 modulus (division) operation, making it at least as expensive as the original division anyway.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, then it's never going to be cheaper if i have to do two divisions at least for that instruction, plus the iteration for the [-1] part, as you said. You've been of great help!